# "npm run serve" giving error in windows cmd

Tags: windows, vue.js, npm, command-prompt, npm-scripts

In windows, when I run the command "npm run serve" in command prompt for viewing my vue js project it is showing some errors

```
C:\Users\HOME\app>npm run serve
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-15T17_29_32_459Z-debug.log
```

The package.json of this is:

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^16.4.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does `node -v` and `npm -v` return something ?

Comment: Make sure this `package.json` you posted is inside C:\Users\HOME\app\, not in a subdirectory.

Comment: @zerbene Yes both commands are giving the versions. There is no problem there

Comment: @FerryKranenburg No, package.json is in the folder "app" . It is not in a subdirectory

Comment: I think you should reinstall Node.

Comment: i done that so many times